# Trying to change primary partition

Tags: ssd, windows-11

I have a new XPS 15 9520. It has two slots for ssd's. The one it came with was the 500gb NVMe. I have put samsung's 1TB NVMe 980 Pro into the second slot. I then cloned the 500gb drive to the 1TB drive using Macrium reflect, with the intention of making the 1tb drive my primary C: drive. I restarted the computer I pressed F12, entered bios, and rearranged the boot order:

[image]

However, it still boots from the old 500gb drive. I think I am having the same problem as [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1106885/how-to-give-new-hard-drive-boot-page-file-crash-dump-status) - because in the disk management, my new drive is just saying it is a basic partition, rather than a boot, page file, crash dump, etc. However, I don't understand the answers and it's 4 years old at this point. What is a good way to make the cloned drive work as the primary drive?

[image]

I know it has a working OS because I can set the computer to boot from the 1TB drive if I open in safe mode and click the onetime boot option for this partition and put in the bitlocker code. However, if I restart it, it goes back to using the 500gb drive as the default.

[image]

Comment: Try to put the 980 Pro as first in the boot order, or else you could exchange the cables for the two disks.

Comment: Have you tried to boot the laptop with the original nvme drive removed?
You may also have to select/set the newer drive as the first boot device within the UEFI as well.

Comment: I haven't tried moving the drives around - does its physical location in either the first or second ssd slot matter? And do you mean moving the 1TB above the boot manager in the boot sequence? The original order was Windows Boot Manager / 500gb drive / 1tb drive / UEFI HTTPS boot, so I figured just switching the 1tb above the 500gb was correct.

Comment: The slot the drive occupies might impact drives performance, but that depends on how the drive is wired on the motherboard (PCIe Gen, CPU/Chipset, etc...)